# Assign array values in each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I'm trying to loop through input fields with an each loop, add other form data to an array and then add that input value to the form data already in the array.

It seems to be basically working but every time I set the input it sets that value in all the entries with that name in the array.  Any ideas about where my logic is going sideways?

```
$(this).next('tr').children('td').each(function () {
        input = $(this).children('input');
        units[i] = unit;
        units[i]['barcode'] = input.val();
        i++;
 });
```

Output object:
 Object {0: Object, 1: Object}
0: Object
barcode: "789"
qty: "3"
size: 15
status: "received"

1: Object
barcode: "789"
qty: "3"
size: 15
status: "received"

The input.val() is different on each iteration of the each loop, it just assigns the last value to all barcode entries.

Comment: What is `unit` and `i`?

Comment: Assuming `unit` is an object defined before your loop, you're assigning every array element to reference the same object. You need to add some code to create a new object on each iteration.

Comment: i is just a counter set to 0 before the loop, unit is an object defined before the loop.

If I'm just assigning the same object over and over and that's why the barcode is being reassigned, is there a good way to deal with this?  unit is base data that the barcode is tagged on to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) with an empty object to clone the unit object so that each array doesn't refer to the same instance:

```
$(this).next('tr').children('td').each(function () {
        input = $(this).children('input');
        units[i] = $.extend({}, unit);
        units[i]['barcode'] = input.val();
        i++;
 });
```

This should work fine now with each object unique, including the barcodes.

Comment: That's the ticket!  
Thank you!